# C++ implementation of 2-3-4 Trees

Tags: c++, 2-3-4-tree

I was looking for  C++ implementation of 2-3-4 Trees online and was surprised that 
There is no code available for it. I couldn't find anything. I have studies this Trees 
But writing code is difficult for me as of now so I wanted to look at some already
implemented code. Is there an easy way to implement it using a 2-3 Tree or some other 
existing Data Structure or one has to start from scratch to implement it ?
Any links/references or ideas will help

Comment: You can see this: - Seems to be a good implementation of 2.3.4 trees :> https://github.com/gabrieledcjr/2-3-4-Tree/blob/master/hw6_234tree.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unlikely to find a production-quality implementation. A red-black tree is an isomorphic structure to a 2-3-4 tree, and is more efficient and easier to work with. So you'll find plenty of RB trees, and they're basically the same thing. (You could rework a RB tree into a 2-3-4 tree but that would just make it worse.)

Comment: Thanks! For an RB tree I have noticed some text define the nodes as red and black whereas other define the edges as red and black. I am not sure if they are same or like how one converts to another. Could you briefly describe that if possible.... I will check out for understanding the isomorphism of RB tree and 2-3-4 tree.  It's interesting because RB is a binary search tree...

Comment: Also what about other trees 2-3 trees and the general extension 2-3-4-5 one could go to any number they like. Do they too have any isomorphic simpler correspondence

Comment: That's a different question. Shortly, though, nodes have colors, not edges, but since each non-root node has exactly one incoming edge, one could notionally assign the color to the edge.

Comment: I'm not aware of a wider variant. 2-3 trees and 2-3-4 trees don't have much of a pattern, so I don't think one could trivially generalize. The closest thing is probably B-trees.

Comment: (But 2-3 trees are isomorphic to AA trees.)